# Overriden @classmethod, type exception

Tags: python, django

I am trying to extend a class whose name is 'Account' (from django-user-accounts app) with my own 'snAccount' class, since I need to add some extra fields to each user account. The problem comes when I try to override the "factory" method (@classmethod) of the parent class with mine:

```
# Original method
@classmethod
def create(cls, request=None, **kwargs):
    ...
    ...

# Override attempt
@classmethod
def create(cls, request=None, **kwargs):
    create_email = kwargs.pop("create_email", True)
    user = kwargs.pop("user", None)
    acc = Account.create(request, user, create_email)
    x_account = cls(account, **kwargs)
    x_account.save()
    return x_account
```

The problem I have throws the following exception:

```
Django Version:     1.4.5
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    create() takes at most 2 arguments (4 given)
Exception Location: /home/.../WebServices/models.py in create, line 27
```

... which I cannot understand since the definition of that method takes 2 implicit arguments and **kwargs in addition. What am I doing wrong? I do not have much experience with Python, as you might see...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't actually *used* any keyword arguments.

```
acc = Account.create(request, user=user, create_email=create_email)
```